# Run JS inside CSS (OnLoad)

Tags: javascript, css

I want to run js inside CSS when the page loaded.
Is this possible?

```
html{
    width: expression(document.getElementById('BeneficiaryLabel').innerHTML = 'test');
}
```

this doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: The expressions were supported only in IE up to version 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is absolutely not possible.

You have it a bit backwards: You'll have to call your Javascript from within the HTML document, not the CSS.

Use the JS to select the CSS then apply your width function.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just have the javascript do it at document load using javascript outside of the CSS file?

You cannot mix CSS with JS, will not work at all.